# convert unix timestamp to H2 timestamp

Tags: timestamp, h2

How do I convert unix timestamp value like `1348560343598` to H2 `Timestamp`?

One of my tables contains these unix timestamps in a `BIGINT(19)` column and I need to convert them to a column of type `TIMESTAMP`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, using the following formula works:

```
select DATEADD('SECOND', 1348560343, DATE '1970-01-01')
```

Just remember to divide the timestamp with 1000. Using `'MILLISECOND'` doesn't work, you will get `Numeric value out of range`.

Comment: Millisecond doesn't work: yes, I ran into the same problem. It's actually a limitation of `Calendar.add(int field, int amount)`, which is used internally. H2 doesn't use `java.util.Calendar` any longer for most date / time features, because of problems with timezones, but in this case it is still used.

Comment: this actually coverts it to JVM time (so you cannot force it to be UTC which is more meaningful for storing timestamps in a database).