# Converting epoch timestamp in H2 database

Tags: java, database, h2, database-administration, h2db

I am having preexisting table name 'ABC' in H2 Database.and description is,

```
FIELD              | TYPE                           | NULL | KEY | DEFAULT
ID                 | DECIMAL(19)                    | NO   |     | NULL
EVENT              | TIMESTAMP(23)                  | YES  |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
```

in 'EVENT' column I have some unix timestamps (epoch time in millisec.) data.

```
ID |   EVENT
1  |  1468318907575 
2  |  1468321000459
```

I have no idea how this has inserted into 'DB'

My concern here is I want to convert data inside 'EVENT' into normal timestamp.

in MYSQL we have FROM_UNIXTIME function to attain this kind of scenario;
But in H2 Database I am not able to find a way out...

please help me in this.

Thanks in advance !!!

Reagrds

Comment: This might help you [convert unix timestamp to H2 timestamp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16012138/convert-unix-timestamp-to-h2-timestamp).

Comment: i checked this one but how do i use it my case ??, i am totally new to this function..

Comment: EXTRACT ( datetimeField FROM dateAndTime )

Returns a value of the specific time unit from a date/time value. This method returns a numeric value with EPOCH field and an int for all other fields.

Example:

EXTRACT(SECOND FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)